# C function calls inside struct without using the same object

Tags: c, function-calls

For example, I have the C code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct a
{
    void(*fun)(struct a *);
    int x;
};

void fun(struct a *st)
{
    ++st->x;
}

struct a *new_a()
{
    struct a *v = (struct a*)malloc(sizeof(struct a));
    v->fun = fun;
    return v;
};

int main()
{
    struct a *v = new_a();
    v->x = 5;
    v->fun(v);
    printf("%d\n", v->x);
}
```

This prints, of course, `6`, however, is there a way of not making the function call dependent of using the same struct to call it: `v->fun();`, rather than `v->fun(v);`?

Comment: Well,... yes.  Define it outside of a `struct`.

Comment: @ryyker This. At least it will save you from referring to your "object" twice and storing function pointers for pretty much no reason, or - like it was mentioned - use C++.

Comment: Can't you add a `struct a * self` inside of `struct a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is **no**. You would need C++ for that.

Answer (score 4):

**No.** In C there is no easy way to do this. C++ provides this feature, it's called methods. If you are going to implement your own *C with classes*, you'll run into a syntax nightmare, before giving up.

A good C-style approach to object-functions will be the convention for functions taking one (mostly the first) parameter as a *"self"* (which is the reference to the object that gets managed).